# Gaussian filter applied to BMP in C

Tags: c, filter, bitmap, gauss

I'm trying to write a code that filters bitmap through Gaussian and some other filters. I have developed a code which generates kernel depending on input parameters such as kernel size and standard deviation. I have also written a code which parses bitmap image and puts it into pointer. My question is, how to apply generated kernel matrix to pointer or is there some other way to apply Gaussian kernel values to this bitmap pointer.

Here in example is my code with different filter (darkenImage) just so you can see my code styling:

```
    int darkenImage(unsigned char* iData, int iWidth, int iHeight)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    unsigned char* ptr = iData;

    for (i=0; i<iHeight; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<iWidth; j++)
        {
            *ptr = *ptr + darkenFactor;
            ptr++;
            *ptr = *ptr + darkenFactor;
            ptr += 1;
            *(ptr++) = *ptr + darkenFactor;
        }
        ptr+=2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is input, output part of the main function

```
printf("Applying dark image\n");
    bitmapData = LoadBitmapFile("ubuntu.bmp",&bitmapFileHeader, &bitmapInfoHeader);
    darkenImage (bitmapData, bitmapInfoHeader.biWidth, bitmapInfoHeader.biHeight);
    err = SaveBitmapFile("out_darken.bmp", &bitmapFileHeader,
    &bitmapInfoHeader, bitmapData);
    if (err)
    {
        printf("Error trying to save bitmap\n");
    }
    free(bitmapData);
```

So, how do I make GaussFilter function?

Comment: there seems to be no effort towards actually writing a GaussianFilter

Comment: @MikeLitoris You need the 2d array for Gaussian filter.

Comment: @Michas I have separate function which successfully creates 2d matrix of Gauss coefficients, how to apply them to ptr?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur

Comment: @MikeLitoris You have to convert ptr of pixels to 2d array. I’m afraid You need two images, one for source and one for destination.

Comment: @Michas How to convert them to 2d array?

Comment: @MikeLitoris The concept of 2d array in C is quite complicated. You have to do some research.